# get file information from Gulp SRC

Tags: node.js, gulp

how can I get info about the current file being processed?

I need to know the name of the parent folder and use the name as a prefix for the new file.

```
return src(targetPath(target) + "/**/*.js")
    .pipe(rename({
        dirname: "./",
        basename: ParentFolderName ???
    }))
    .pipe(dest(targetPath(targets.CREATORScriptBuild)));
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, this works:

```
    return src(targetPath(target) + "/**/*.js")
        .pipe(rename((file) => {
            if (file.dirname !== ".") {
                file.basename = file.dirname + "." + file.basename;
                file.dirname = "./";
            }
        }))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(dest(targetPath(targets.CREATORScriptBuild)));
}
```